# Positive and Negative votes

Tags: support, voting, answers

I recently noticed that when an answer has a positive amount of votes, It looks exactly the same as when there are no votes. On the other hand, when an answer has a negative amount of votes it fades when the mouse is not hovering over it. Does this fade increase with the amount of negative votes, or is it the same for all negatives?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the exact trigger, but a similar thing happens with questions: if a question reaches -3 votes, it is banished from the front page.

Comment: cool, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fade comes into effect at a score of -3. It's basically an easy way to distinguish good answers from bad ones.

Comment: It's different on meta though right? It seems to be about -7 or -8

Comment: @Robotnik [This answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/last-chance-top-domain-name-pauseforhelp-com-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your/1103#1103) is at -3 and greyed out on meta (The question is a great collection of downvoted answers on meta in general.)

Comment: @MrLemon - Ah, I remember what it was now. A question at < -3 won't be shown on the frontpage, on meta it's < -8